# I have a cluster of computers, how do I setup ntpd so they all have nearly the same clock?

Tags: ntp, cluster

I have 4 computers, one is considered the master (direct connection to the Internet) and the others are considered slaves (for those the master adds one extra hop to any external communication.)

At this time, all computers are setup to have time synchronized through external time servers (a.k.a. 0.north-america.pool.ntp.org). Is that the way you would do it too?

I am wondering whether setting up the ntpd of each slave to accept clock adjustments from the master instead of external sources could be better?

Comment: Do you really care if their clocks differ by a few milliseconds?

Comment: Me personally? Not really. However, systems like Cassandra and timed network messages need to have clocks that are as close as possible to avoid inconsistencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, you'd set an ntp server up on a single machine on your network, possibly your router or gateway.  That machine would call out to ntp servers over the Internet and make sure its time is accurate.  You will want to provide a few ntp servers in your region.  It will also provide time information to your LAN.  There are many tutorials on how to get this done properly for a LAN-only setup.

The other machines on your LAN would then make ntp requests to the ntp server on your LAN.  Your LAN ntp server will be the only machine they would query.

This would be the best method of making sure the machines on your LAN have near-matching times, as well as ensuring the LAN doesn't get get out of sync with the rest of the world.